# mailbox migration complete but nothing happen

Tags: migration, mailbox, exchange-2016

I migrated 5 huge size mailboxes (maximum is 50GB) to my new exchange database in exchange 2016. After waiting couples of hours, I got success migration message but those mailboxes are still in old exchange database (Check the below screenshot). How can I sort it out?

[image]

Comment: Has moving this mailbox failed on previous move requests?  Is this user part of a another move request too?

Comment: Actually that migrate is for second 5 users. The first 5 users migration successed.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t see your screenshot. May I know how did you check the database? You could move only one mailbox for test and increase–baditemlimit.  Or you can export the data to pst file and import it to his mailbox after move.

Comment: I tried only one of them to move and increased baditem limit to 100 but still nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following cmdlet 
Get-MigrationUser | Remove-MigrationUser -Force

Then clear the followings for the move user in ADSI:

msExchMailboxMoveFlags
msExchMailboxMoveSourceMDBLink

msExchMailboxMoveStatus

msExchMailboxMoveTargetMDBLink

and try to move the mailbox again.